# Controller error in Angular Script - [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, controller, couchdb

I'm not sure about the controller syntax. I keep getting an [$injector:modulerr] error which leads me to believe that it's the controller playing up but I'm lost otherwise. My main objective at the moment is that I'm trying to "get" and display all the results from a couchdb database.

```
<div ng-app="guestBook">
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js">
</script>

<script>
    var guestBook = angular.module('guestBook', ['ngRoute'])
    guestBook.controller('CouchController', ['$scope', '$http', '$get', function ($scope, $http, $get) {
        // View everything in database
        $scope.view = function () {
            var json = {};
            var url = "https://sophia.iriscouch.com/guestbook/_all_docs";
            $get({
                url: url,
                method: 'GET',
                data: json,
                dataType: "jsonp",
            }).success(function (json, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(json);
            })
        };
        // Creating a new instance on couchDB
        $scope.submit = function () {
            var entry = {
                "Name": $scope.name,
                    "Comment": $scope.comment
            };
            console.log(entry);
            var timestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
            var url = 'https://sophia.iriscouch.com/guestbook/' + timestamp;
            console.log(url);
            $http({
                url: url,
                method: 'PUT',
                data: entry,
                dataType: "json",
                withCredentials: true,
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': auth_hash("sophia", "Einstein1")
                }
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(headers);
                console.log(config);
            });
        }
        function auth_hash(username, password) {
            var str = window.btoa(username + ":" + password);
            return 'Basic' + str;
        }
    }]);
</script>



<form ng-controller="CouchController">
    <p>
        <input type="text" ng-model="comment">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="text" ng-model="name">
    </p>

    <p>
        <button ng-click="submit()">Add</button>
    </p>
    <p>
        <button ng-click="view()">show</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you specify the dependent `ngRoute` module like

```
 angular.module('guestBook', ['ngRoute'])
```

but you didn't  add `angular-route.js` script file. adding that file will solve this.

here is the CDN of [ngRoute](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.6/angular-route.js) module

---

after adding it the code should be like,

```
<div ng-app="guestBook">
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.6/angular-route.js"></script>
....
```